# Question regarding notation for semidirect product

Tags: finite-groups, terminology, semidirect-product, convention

When you say that

> $G$ is a semidirect product of (a cyclic group of prime order) by (a
>   finite abelian group of odd order)

does that imply the direction of the symbol for semidirect product (which will enable us to identify the normal subgroup)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no widely accepted convention. It is better to specify it, for instance by saying "$G$ is a semi-direct product of $\ldots$ **acting on** $\ldots$", or by writing down explicitly $G\simeq H\rtimes K$ after defining $H$ and $K$.

Comment: So that means if you just say as above it will not imply about the normal subgroup, right?

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika Exactly. Some people may have a preferred convention, but it is not written in stone.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

Comment: @BuddhiniAngelika You're welcome.